# How to i get the click function to stop working when the last child is shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the html, the pages-nr have a fixed width with an overflow:hidden :

```
<div class="pages-scroll">
    <div class="pages-rightarrow"></div>
    <div class="articles-pages">
       <div class="pages-nr">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>                          
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">4</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">5</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">6</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">7</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">8</a>
       </div>
     </div> 
     <div class="pages-leftarrow"></div>
</div>
```

This is the script i wrote so far and i donno what to ask 'if' to do so the arrows will be hidden when i reach the last div or the first div.

```
$('.pages-leftarrow').click(function () {
    if ( $('.pages-nr a').hasClass('????') ) {
        $('.pages-rightarrow').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.pages-nr').css({"margin-left": function(index, value) {
            return parseFloat(value) - 44}
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Na3W7/4/
This is the meat of the code that's run on startup:

```
$('.pages-nr a:not(:first),.pages-leftarrow').hide();
$('.pages-rightarrow').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $nextPage = $('.pages-nr a:visible:first').hide().next().show();
    if($nextPage.is('.pages-nr a:last-child')){
        $(e.target).hide();
    }
    if($('.pages-nr a:first').is(':visible')) {
        $('.pages-leftarrow').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.pages-leftarrow').show();
    }

});
$('.pages-leftarrow').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $prevPage = $('.pages-nr a:visible:first').hide().prev().show();
    if($prevPage.is('.pages-nr a:first-child')){
        $(e.target).hide();
    }
    if($('.pages-nr a:last').is(':visible')) {
        $('.pages-rightarrow').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.pages-rightarrow').show();
    }

});
```

Comment: this works fine for the rightarrow, but how do i hide the left arrow when the i first load the page and show it when i hide the first-child. Also after i reach the last-child the right arrow is hidden but when i jump back to the previous child the right arrow does not become visible.

Comment: Updated answer to include fiddle and complete logic. You can probably replace the arrow show/hide if-else with the jquery .toggle(boolean) function.